# How can I change my date time of my DVDCopy table to number of days then join it with table DVD's Title and DVDCopy's Cop_id Columns?

Tags: asp.net

**

select a.Dvd_id,a.Title,(SELECT DATEDIFF(day,Date_added,GETDATE()) from DVDCopy) Total_days from DVD as a inner join DVDCopy as b on a.Dvd_id=b.Dvd_id;

**

**I then go this error**

### Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: This was the error I had.

Comment: Please add details about the schema.